# WPF play youtube video

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to embed a youtube video into WebBrowser, however, it shows just a blank screen

```
<WebBrowser util:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding UrlContent}"/>
```

---

DI:

```
public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;
        if (browser != null)
        {
            string uri = e.NewValue as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri)) return;
            browser.NavigateToString(uri);
            
        }
    }
```

---

Output:

[image]

Tried:

- Formated HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
                <html>
                   <head>
                   </head>
<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/diB65scQU' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
                   <body>
                   </body>
                </html>
```

- Plain Link => http://www.youtube.com/embed/diB65scQU
- http://www.youtube.com/embed/diB65scQU

Results - the same - just a blank view

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebView2 control instead, it is an official replacement, take a look [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf).
See [WebView2Samples on github](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser)

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have 
some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the 
target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)